# localstack Aws cloudwatch logs

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, localstack

How to send logs to localstack cloudwatch logs using node.

i am using npm

```
const winston = require('winston')
const CloudWatchTransport = require('winston-aws-cloudwatch')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using `winston-cloudwatch` instead as `winston-aws-cloudwatch` because it is more in use and is maintained. But as the choice is yours and if you still want to use `winston-aws-cloudwatch`, you can add the endpoint in awsConfig to `http://localhost:4586`, because by default localstack uses `4586` as port for cloudwatch.

Example for `winston-cloudwatch` is given below.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const WinstonCloudWatch = require('winston-cloudwatch');
 
winston.add(new WinstonCloudWatch({
  awsRegion: 'us-east-1',
  logGroupName: 'your-log-group-name',
  logStreamName: 'your-log-stream-name',
  jsonMessage: true,
}));

winston.info('I am done');
```

or

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const WinstonCloudWatch = require('winston-cloudwatch');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new WinstonCloudWatch({
      logGroupName: 'log-group-name',
      logStreamName: 'log-stream-name',
      awsRegion: 'us-east-1',
      jsonMessage: true
    })
  ]
});

logger.error('I am done');
```

The snippet may end in `Invalid token error`. You can use `awslocal iam` to create an IAM user and create an access key with the same and use it.

You may need to install [awslocal](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local) if you wanna play with `localstack`

To verify if the log group has been created or not, you can try with
`awslocal logs describe-log-groups`

For other CLI commands, you can refer [AWS CLI documetation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html#cli-aws)

For local, you can replace `aws` to `awslocal`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this example `https://github.com/lazywithclass/winston-cloudwatch/blob/747ae3c2292fdae6c046394938f159b4c7a23802/examples/simple.js`

```
var winston = require('winston'),
WinstonCloudWatch = require('../index');


// when you don't provide a name the default one
// is CloudWatch
winston.add(new WinstonCloudWatch({
  logGroupName: 'testing',
  logStreamName: 'first',
  awsRegion: 'us-east-1'
}));

winston.error('1');
```

Advanced example using `winston-cloud`

https://github.com/lazywithclass/winston-cloudwatch/blob/747ae3c2292fdae6c046394938f159b4c7a23802/examples/multiple-loggers.js